# sitemap localization not working

Tags: localization, master-pages, sitemap, globalization, app-globalresources

Strange things happening. If I have only one file filename.en-US.resx file in App_GlobalResources. Sitemap(Which is referring as "$resources:Web.sitemap,key") is throwing error that object or key couldnt find. But when i have two files filename.en-US.resx and filename.resx[this has no keys it is empty], sitemap is working fine. Please need some explanation.

Comment: Does anyone know where to start looking for this code in Reflector?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a `filename.resx` that acts as the normal (invariant) resource before adding culture/language specific resource files.

Comment: it shouldnt be an issue because prior to that the culture is being set.